# How to iterate through dynamically generated combo boxes with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am using html.erb to generate views in a **rails** app.

I am generating combo boxes using `"each do | |"`

How to iterate through values dynamically generated combo boxes using jquery and alert the user if any of the values of the combo boxes are same.

```
    <table class="holiday_allowance_schedule tabular_data_cell">
  <thead>
    <th class="years_from_accrual_start">
      <%= a(:company_policy, :years_from_accrual_start) %>
    </th>
    <th class="months_allocated"><%= a(:company_policy, :days_allocated) %></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="schedule_table">
    <% @policies.holiday_allocation_schedule.keys.sort.each do |year| -%>
      <tr id="<%= year %>">
        <% days = @policies.holiday_allocation_schedule[year] %>

        <td><%= select_tag("holiday_schedule[][year]", options_for_select(holiday_allocation_years_options, year)) %></td> #combo boxes with years

        <td><%= select_tag("holiday_schedule[][days]", options_for_select(holiday_allocation_days_options, days)) %></td>
        <td class="actions"><%= add_icon %></td>
        <td class="actions"><%= remove_icon %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end -%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For ex: there are five combo boxes

1 year

2 years

3 years

4 years

5 years

if user select "3 years" in any two or more combo boxes an alert has to shown

how to accomplish this using jquery or using erb itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind a change() listener to all of your combo box, do the checking inside there.

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var values = []
   $.each($('select'), function(idx, sel){
     if(values.index(sel.val()) != -1){
       alert('same value selected')
     }else{
       values.push(sel.val())
     }
   })
})
```

Comment: Please add additional information to this answer, some example code for instance.

Comment: sorry nickcen, I can't understand your answer

Comment: @YasirAzzu the logic is as follow. you should bind a change() listener to all the select input. When any of the select input value get change, the listener will get called. The logic inside the listener is to get back the value of all the select, and see whether there are two select has the same values.